# How to Master the HTML/CSS in Weebly

Tags: html, css, customization, developer-tools, weebly

I’m trying to update a client’s existing website with:

1. Centered links in the navigation
2. Social Media links on the right side of the navigation
3. A Sidebar on the right side of the Home page that would contain links to their blog

My problem is that they use Weebly and I’ve found the Settings to be extremely limited! I can access the developer coding, but my understanding of that is very basic. Has anyone added these sort of things to Weebly? Is there any CSS I can drop in?

I tried a couple of tutorials from Weebly Tricks on YouTube but he was using different themes and the vids were from 2017 so nothing was working.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=62&v=8FOw2rpYzBA&feature=emb_title

And I found a great pre-built sidebar on Codepen, but I tried to place it in my Content area and it went dead center over top of everything on the Home page:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/25tcm5bmhomlaaw/Screenshot%202020-07-03%2016.48.13.png?dl=0

I copied the existing site and I’m working in a free Weebly domain as a beta test:
https://aapreview.weebly.com/

Comment: Try this https://smallbusiness.chron.com/put-css-templates-weebly-47029.html